# google apps script - send the next line every day from spreadsheets to discord

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

I'm helping an educational project.
The following is the request:

the words-sentences in 1 row from a google spreadsheets list should be sent automatically to the discord text channal every day. The next day, a line below. When the whole list is finished, it should go back to the beginning and send it again. and write it on a new line after each column.

2nd request: same but this time 2 rows should be sent every day.
Number of columns Generally the same 2 or 3.

this is the code i found works, but that's not what i wanted. this code is for:"a range of cells".

How do I get it to send the next line every day? I will set the code to run once a day with Trigger from the menu. But how will it know which line it sent yesterday, etc.?

Unfortunately, I couldn't do exactly what I wanted. I will be glad if you help

(I'm an IT person, but I don't have any coding knowledge. I understand the code when I see it, but I can't write it.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv8fK.png)

```
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loot");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C3");
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process

  var data = range.getValues();
  var result = '';

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
      result = result.concat(d[j]);
   }
}


  message = message || result ;

  var discordUrl = 'webhook xxx';

  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Edit:

```
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("b1");
  var propertyServ = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var properties = propertyServ.getProperties(); //get script properties
  var row = 1; // set initial row
  var incRow = 4; // how much row
  if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(properties).length != 0){ //this will check if the properties object is not empty
    row = parseInt(properties["row"]) + incRow; //increase row
  }
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, incRow, 6);

  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var d = values[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
      result = result.concat(d[j]);
   }
}


  message = message || result ;

  var discordUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks xxx';

  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  propertyServ.setProperty("row", row); //save the current row of processed line

}
```

Comment: You could store historical information in Properties Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Cooper, you can use the Properties Service of Google Apps Script to save the processed range in your code.

Here I have an example which you can incorporate to your code.

### EDIT

Revised code to process 3 rows and print each row per line.

**Test Data:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function propertyServExample() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loot");
  var propertyServ = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var properties = propertyServ.getProperties(); //get script properties
  var row = 1; // set initial row
  if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(properties).length != 0){ //this will check if the properties object is not empty
    row = parseInt(properties["row"]) + 3;
  }
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 3, 2);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var str = '';
  values.forEach(val => {
    str = str + val.join('') + '\n';
  })
  Logger.log(str);
  propertyServ.setProperty("row", row); //save the current row of processed line
}
```

Each run will get the next row.

Run 1:

[image]

Run 2:

[image]

Run 3:

[image]

### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: thanks. this helped. 
but I'm having trouble getting to the new line.
for example it prints 3 lines. There is no space between columns, but I want some distance.
and I want it to write each line on a new line.
ex:
A1B1C1
but it muss:
'''
A   1
(>new line>)B    2
(>new line>)C    3
'''

Comment: I guess i have to type this for notification to go? @Nikko J. @+Nikko J.

Comment: Do you mean you want to process/print 3 row per run and increment the row counter by 3?

Comment: No, I somehow handled it. but all the texts are stuck together and form a single line, so it is difficult to read. for example; apple1apple2apple3bus1bus2bus3
but i want: 1.row must 1.line, 2.row must 2.line, 3.row 3.line

Comment: I added the current code to my message above, after the "edit" at the bottom

Comment: @mrA. - I updated my answer. Let me know if my understanding of your problem is correct.

Comment: yes it is complete now. perfect. thanks :)